# How to add multiple columns to R dataframe from list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df1

a b c
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 1

df2

a b c d e f
1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2
```

How can I add new columns to `df1` from `df2` that aren't in `df1`? to get:

```
df2

a b c d e f
1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
```

I tried:

```
columns_toadd <- colnames(df1)[!(colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2))]

for (i in 1:length(columns_toadd)){
  df$columns_toadd[[i]] <- 0
}
```

But this just gave:

```
df2

a b c columns_toadd
1 1 0 0 
1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 0
```

I'd like to do this in base R as I work in an environment with limited packages.

Comment: Try `df1[setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))] <-  0`

Comment: What is definition of new column? Is it column name or content? Also, number of rows differ.

Comment: @akrun I just want the names of the columns in `df2` not in `df1` added onto `df1` with a 0 in each row. I'm not focussed on the length atm.

Comment: @Chuck In that case, please check the updated comment above

Comment: @Chuck akrun's code will give you exactly that

Comment: @akrun. Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Happy to accept if answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the column names that are not in 'df1' using `setdiff` and assign those to 0

```
df1[setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))] <- 0
```